# Lombok onlyExplicitlyIncluded configuration key

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using Lombok in my project. In my model I've a superclass annotated like this:

```
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Persistable<Long>, Serializable {
}
```

and tons of subclasses annotated:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class EyeReport extends AbstractEntity {
}
```

Because all of them are annoteted in this way, I was wondering if there is a way to set the `onlyExplicitlyIncluded` to true in `lombok.config` in order to avoid a bit of boilerplate annotations in hundreds of classes.

My file right now is:

```
lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = call
lombok.toString.callSuper = call
```

I checkd [Lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) but I didn't find that property, not sure why. Do you have any hint to reduce annotations in my example?

Comment: Remark unrelated to your question: If you use `@SuperBuilder` on your base class, why not on the subclasses?

Comment: @JanRieke thanks for your hint. Maybe you are right. I thought SuperBuilder had to stay only in the superclass

Comment: On the contrary: `@SuperBuilder` is not compatible with `@Builder`. In your case, you'll get separate builders on all classes that don't relate to each other, so you won't have any benefit in using `@SuperBuilder`.